# Bash interpreting associative array keys as octal numbers

Tags: bash, associative-array

How do I prevent this from failing:

```
a[5c8]=1
-bash: 5c8: value too great for base (error token is "5c8")
```

It seems that bash interprets 5c8 as an octal number. Obviously, I could add a prefix to the key and remove that prefix later when using the array, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Bash 4.3.48.

Comment: Adding a prefix isn't obvious and doesn't work. It'll just evaluate as a variable that's unlikely to exist, and therefore be equivalent to `a[0]`

Comment: The digit "c" is too great for base 10.

Comment: I *am* curious where the OP got the idea that octal was involved. (It can be, if the key starts with a 0, but that's not the case here).

Comment: 5c8 looks like a hex number to me, but bash is not so clever. Have you tried adding an 0x prefix?

Comment: `bash` can't be clever, because it's also a valid base-13, base-14, ..., and base-64 number.

Comment: `for ((b=13;b<=64;b++)); do echo $(($b#5c8)); done`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*All* array keys are interpreted as numbers (or names of variables to be evaluated to obtain a number) unless you declare the array as associative, as with `declare -A`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[1-3].*) echo "Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A a
a[5c8]=1
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you have an indexed array, so the index is evaluated in an arithmetic context.

Second, any string starting with a numeral will be treated as a number, as opposed to an identifier with a numeric value.

```
$ foo=3
$ a[foo]=5
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([3]="5")
```

So what number is 5c8? `bash` has a rich set of numeric literals available:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A leading
>          0x or  0X  denotes  hexadecimal.   Otherwise,  numbers  take  the  form
>          [base#]n,  where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64
>          representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that  base.   If
>          base#  is omitted, then base 10 is used.  When specifying n, the digits
>          greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the  uppercase
>          letters, @, and _, in that order.  If base is less than or equal to 36,
>          lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably  to  represent numbers between 10 and 35.

It's not a valid constant in base 10 (the default). It *is* valid for base 13 or higher, but `bash` won't try to guess which one you mean.

---

All that said, you probably mean that to be treated as a literal string, in which case you need to declare the array as an associative array, so that indices aren't evaluated in an arithmetic context.

```
$ declare -A a
$ a[5c8]=1
$ declare -p a
declare -A a=([5c8]="1" )
```